# SwiftUI widget Text.DateStyle not working in iOS 16

Tags: xcode, swiftui, widget, ios16

I have a widget with a countdown timer. I've been using "Text(event.startDate, style: .timer)" to update the widget text. But after updating to iOS 16 this stoped working. Have anyone experienced the same? Dosn't look like its deprecated either https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/datestyle/timer

Comment: I'm having the same issue with my app. I filed feedback bug: FB11503070. Please do the same and can reference that ticket. It's a painful bug I hope gets resolved in a minor release soon.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/713008